# I believe this should be one rule in Treetop

Tags: ruby, treetop

I have this working pair of rules in Treetop that the perfectionist in me believes should be one and only one rule, or maybe something more beautiful at least:

```
rule _
  crap
  /
  " "*
end

rule crap
  " "* "\\x0D\\x0A"* " "*
end
```

I'm parsing some expressions that every now and then ended up with "\x0D\x0A". Yeah, not "\r\n" but "\x0D\x0A". Something was double escaped at some point. Long story.

That rule works, but it's ugly and it bothers me. I tried this:

```
rule _
  " "* "\\x0D\\x0A"* " "*
  /
  " "*
end
```

which caused

```
SyntaxError: (eval):1276:in `load_from_string': compile error
(eval):1161: class/module name must be CONSTANT
    from /.../gems/treetop-1.4.9/lib/treetop/compiler/grammar_compiler.rb:42:in `load_from_string'
    from /.../gems/treetop-1.4.9/lib/treetop/compiler/grammar_compiler.rb:35:in `load'
    from /.../gems/treetop-1.4.9/lib/treetop/compiler/grammar_compiler.rb:32:in `open'
    from /.../gems/treetop-1.4.9/lib/treetop/compiler/grammar_compiler.rb:32:in `load'
```

Ideally I would like to actually write something like:

```
rule _
  (" " | "\\x0D\\x0A")*
end
```

but that doesn't work, and while we are at it, I also discovered that you can't have only one * per rule:

```
rule _
  " "*
  /
  "\n"*
end
```

that will match " ", but never \n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're using three different `OR` chars: `/`, `|` and `\` (of which only the first means `OR`).

This works fine:

```
grammar Language

  rule crap
    (" " / "\\x0D\\x0A")* {
      def value
        text_value    
      end
    }
  end

end
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'treetop'
require 'polyglot'
require 'language'

parser = LanguageParser.new
value = parser.parse(' \\x0D\\x0A   \\x0D\\x0A   ').value
print '>' + value + '<'
```

prints:

```
> \x0D\x0A   \x0D\x0A   <
```

Comment: The third OR char was a typo, the second one was an regex OR (and a hypothetical example. Thanks for the answer, I'll give a try right away.

Comment: @J. Pablo Fernández, yeah, I thought so, but wanted to make sure you weren't trying with an "illegal" `OR`. It's easy to glance over it without noticing.

Answer (score 1):

You said "I also discovered that you can't have only one * per rule" (you mean: you CAN have), "that will match " ", but never \n".

Of course; the rule succeeds when it matches zero space characters. You could just use a + instead:

```
rule _
  " "+
  /
  "\n"*
end
```

You could also parenthesise the space characters if you want to match any number of space-or-newline characters:

```
rule _
  (" " / "\n")*
end
```

Your error "class/module name must be CONSTANT" is because the rule name is used as the prefix of a module name to contain any methods attached to your rule. A module name may not begin with an underscore, so you can't use methods in a rule whose name begins with an underscore.